# Validate schema with joi TypeError when property not exists

Tags: node.js, typeerror, joi

I'm getting an error while validating my schema using [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)

So I've written this:

```
const joiSchema = Joi.object().options({ abortEarly: false }).keys({
  stream_name: Joi.string().required(),
  audio_bitrate: Joi.number().integer().min(80).required()
  ...
});
```

and in my get method

```
data.forEach((item) => {
  const result = Joi.validate({
    stream_name: item.value.name,
    audio_bitrate: item.value.stats.media_info.streams[0].bitrate,
},
joiSchema,
(err, val) => {
 console.log(err);
});
```

But when streams not exists I'm getting an `typeError`

> audio_bitrate: item.value.stats.media_info.streams[0].bitrate,
>                                                       ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'streams' of undefined

How can I handle this? validation working without any problem if bitrate is less than 80 but when it doesn't exist application goes in exception..

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing deep nested values before validating, it is your responsability to check for errors, joi is not even called here.

If you want joi to do it, you have to give it the full `item` schema.